# Call Objective-c function from javascript on webview

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

recently i´ve done this interact, when i was looking for information i´ve seen that there is not so much on web, so, now that I´ve solve it I want to share

First in your App

On .h

Import

```
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>
```

Declare

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) JSContext *js;
```

On .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

     NSString *address = @"http://yourpage.com";

     // Build the url and loadRequest
     NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",address];
     [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

     //Get JSContext from webview
     self.js = [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

     //Set Delegate to JS object
     self.js[@"Delegate"] = self;

     //Set Handlers to events on JS
     self.js[@"Delegate"][@"FuncWithParams"] = ^(NSString *param1) {
         [self FuncWithParams:param1];
     };

     self.js[@"Delegate"][@"FuncWithoutParams"] = ^{
         [self FuncWithoutParams];
     };

}

//Handlers
- (void)FuncWithParams:(NSString *)param1 {
     NSLog(@"Param =%@", param1);
     //Do what you want
}

- (void)FuncWithoutParams {
    NSLog(@"FuncWithoutParams");
    //Do what you want
}
```

Now, in your webpage

```html
<html>
        <body>
                <input type="button" value="Function With Parameter" onClick="FuncWithParams('Hello World!')"/>
                <input type="button" value="Function Without Parameter" onClick="FuncWithoutParams()" />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function FuncWithParams(param1) {
                        Delegate.FuncWithParams(param1); 
                    }

                    function FuncWithoutParams() {
                        Delegate.FuncWithoutParams();
                    }
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.